# initializing bits of structure which contains other structures C++

Tags: c++, struct, bit-manipulation

I have a struct variable like below.(I've changed the variables names thus they are not meaningful.) I have a problem with initializing bits of myStruct1 array.

I need to initialize `myStruct1.id.lengthOfData` for example 40 and `numberOfBits.number`=16. To do that I've tried to use memset and etc but I couldnt do it correctly. How could I do that rather than doing it manually ? Thanks in advance.

```
#define unsigned int INT32U
typedef struct{
    struct{
        INT32U lengthOfData  :16;                       
        INT32U command   :8;                                                            
        INT32U sendBack  :1;                                
        INT32U backTest  :1;                                        
        INT32U required :1;                 
        INT32U reserved  :5;                                        
        INT32U student_class_id ;                      
    }id;
    union{
        INT32U number;
        struct{
            INT32U firstFiveBits:5;                          
            INT32U secondFiveBits:5;                        
            INT32U thirdFiveBits :5;                                                                                                                                                    INT32U eightBits :8;                        
            INT32U secondEightBits :8;                              
            INT32U restOfit:1;                          
        }numberOfbits;
    }foo;
    union{
        INT32U numberTwo;
        struct{
            INT16U firstSteenBits:16;
            INT16U secondSteenBits  :16;
        }bits;      
    }myUnion;
}myStruct1;
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I've done so far.

```
myStruct1 *myPtr;
    myPtr = new myStruct1;


    memset((myPtr), 0, sizeof(*myPtr)); // to zeros for all bits of myStruct1
    memset((myPtr), 3,1); // to give 3 to lengthOfData.
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? Also: you might want to try with bitwise operations as well as the simplest thing to try out

Comment: @MarcoA. I've added it into my question

Comment: @MarcoA. I've also edited it with my last version of code

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with bit fields you can just use and initialize them as a normal struct field

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define INT32U unsigned int
#define INT16U unsigned short

typedef struct{
    struct{
        INT32U lengthOfData  :16;                       
        INT32U command   :8;                                                            
        INT32U sendBack  :1;                                
        INT32U backTest  :1;                                        
        INT32U required :1;                 
        INT32U reserved  :5;                                        
        INT32U student_class_id ;                      
    }id;
    union{
        INT32U number;
        struct{
            INT32U firstFiveBits:5;                          
            INT32U secondFiveBits:5;                        
            INT32U thirdFiveBits :5;                                                                                                                                                    INT32U eightBits :8;                        
            INT32U secondEightBits :8;                              
            INT32U restOfit:1;                          
        }numberOfbits;
    }foo;
    union{
        INT32U numberTwo;
        struct{
            INT16U firstSteenBits:16;
            INT16U secondSteenBits  :16;
        }bits;      
    }myUnion;
}myStruct1;

int main() {
    myStruct1 obj;
    obj.id.required = 1; // Make sure not to exceed the bit capacity
    obj.id.lengthOfData = 22; // Make sure not to exceed the bit capacity
    cout << obj.id.lengthOfData << endl;
    cout << obj.id.required << endl;
    obj.id.required = 0;
    cout << obj.id.required << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/PUSp1h

Just make sure not to exceed the capacity of the bit field itself and **don't rely on the order of the fields into a single machine word**

Comment: @Marco_A. thanks for reply, you're right for it. How about for example id.required (I asked it because its only a single bit.) Could I initialize it by using obj.id.required=1 ?

Comment: @Marco_A. you're emphasising the using memset is wrong idea ? (with bold line ?)

Comment: @newbornToCS no, but if you need to set fields directly without byte-addressing, this way is easier and more practical. I edited the question with an example for required though.